# Unable to pass $user variable using Auth::user() in Laravel Profile controller

Tags: php, laravel

I just started learning Laravel a week ago, and I've run into an issue with middleware and using Auth::user().  For Laravel >5.3, you can no longer pass session variables within the controller.  I want to be able to pass the $user model back into the blade file (entered in as {{$user->avatar}} within an URL string), but I don't know how to do it.

I spent an entire day (based on suggestions from https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors)), and I consistently get null values, with the error (Undefined variable: user).  I'm really at a loss of how to proceed, and will be grateful if anyone could help me.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Image;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function profile($id)
    {
        $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('user.profile',compact('user'));
    }

    public function update_avatar(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename));

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();
            dd($user);
        }
        return view('user.profile',compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Comment: in your `profile()` method, what do you get if you `dd(Auth::user())`? Assuming you're logged in

Comment: I get the fillable, hidden, attributes, original, and other properties.  The arrays are all full, with values.  Strange.

Comment: So dd($user) does not work, but dd(Auth::user()) does.

Comment: Yeah because `$user` likely isn't being defined wherever you're using it inside a `dd()`, which is why I made it a variable and use it after in the answer I put below

Comment: But this was after I defined it using Auth::user().

Comment: Then I'm not sure of the issue, can you update the question with the code you're trying at the minute. I thought my answer answered your original question so im a bit confused

Comment: Sure, I just updated it in my original post.  Forgot to comment out the dd($user) part.

Comment: Your `update_avatar` method should ideally have the `$user = Auth::user();` before the `if`

Comment: That seems to have worked (no more error!), but nothing gets posted.

Comment: And why does that make a difference?  Should you not declare variables in conditional statements?

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as correct as it's answered your original question please? in your `if` do a `dd($request)`

Comment: Because you're checking to see if something exists in the request, that doesn't really have an effect on if the user object, so its a good idea to define it before any conditionals

Comment: Also, `compact('user')` only makes an array with a string, not the User

Comment: I think I see what the issue here is.  After the dd($request), I saw the file was being uploaded correctly.  The issue was that the files were too large, for which the if block won't execute.

Comment: @masshakar I'm glad you've managed to sort it, can you please mark an answer as correct now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `dd(Auth::user())` inside the `profile()` method returned your expected data, try this:

```
public function profile(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('profile', compact('user'));
}
```

You should then be able to do `{{ $user->id }}` in your blade file. I know the above code is similar to what you have but it's worth a shot!

Comment: That does work, but why am I unable to access the user variable with the update_avatar method?  The form action attribute is "{{ action('ProfileController@profile', $user->id) }}", the method is "POST", I have the csrf_token() as an input, and I have the web route set to:  Route::post('/profile/{id}', ['uses' =>'ProfileController@update_avatar']);

Comment: So you're telling the form POST to use the `profile` method but you're expecting it to use the `update_avatar` method? Is it possible you're missing some vital info in your question as my answer above answers your original question @masshakar

Comment: See comments of original post for details

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass an authenticated user from the controller.

In your Blade template, just directly use this, for example:

```
{{ Auth::user()->id }}
```

This assumes User is logged in.

Comment: This works, however, I want to have the variable $user.  I want to be able to view other user profiles with their data, and Auth::user() will return my info instead of the other user's info.

Comment: @masshakar in this case, you can pass the other user's ID from the view to your controller, then get that User in the controller function, before operating on its Avatar. That user's ID is enough.

Comment: @masshakar so far, your update function updates only the logged in user's avatar.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own admin auth guard.
As your dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user()) inside the your profile() method returned your expected data for login admin user, try this:

```
public function profile(){
     $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
     return view('profile', compact('user'));
}
```

You should then be able to do {{ $user->id }} in your blade file. I know the above code is similar to what you have but it's worth a short.

if you create your own auth guard use tha auth data then use user() method with your auth guard name.